# Where do you put an AsyncTask that would load data on a ListFragment?

Tags: android, xmlhttprequest

So as the question states, where would I put the AsyncTask that would hopefully load data onto a ListFragment?

My MainActivity have three fragments. One is a ListFragment that would contain categories. The Middle one is a Fragment that would contain data retrieved by selecting from categories. And the last one is another ListFragment that would show the ones that the user have selected.

Each of the three fragments have their own xml files and their own .java files. The Main Activity cml file is where I define the three fragments through fragment tags. It works just fine when I am not loading any data on to the first list fragment. But when I start loading data from a remote server through http request it fails. I am using AsyncTask to achieve it.

Here is the java file

MenuCategory.java

```
package com.thesis.menubook;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class MenuCategory extends ListFragment {
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> categoryList;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // LOAD CATEGORY ONTO LIST
        new GetCategories().execute();

    }


    class GetCategories extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
             super.onPreExecute();
             pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
             pDialog.setMessage("Loading Categories. Please wait...");
             pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
             pDialog.setCancelable(false);
             pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... param) {
            Bundle b = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
            String ipaddress = b.getString("IPAddress");

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            Log.d("IP ADDRESS", ipaddress +" ");

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("http://"+ipaddress+"/MenuBook/selectCategories.php", "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Categories: ", json.toString() + " ");

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt("success");

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products

                    JSONArray category_list = json.getJSONArray("category_list");

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int j = 0; j < category_list.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject c = category_list.getJSONObject(j);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String category = c.getString("category");


                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put("category", category);
                        int num = 1;
                        Log.d("category #"+num+"", category + "");
                        num++;
                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        if(categoryList.contains(map) != true)
                        {
                            categoryList.add(map);
                        }
                    }
                } 
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>(getActivity().
                    getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_menu_category);
            arrayAdapter.add(categoryList);
            setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }

}
```

Am I doing this correctly? Or should I put it on the Main Activity instead?

Comment: It's fine to keep the task in the Fragment. If you tell us more about how it is failing and include a logcat trace we can help you more.

Comment: Please refer to this question then : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853317/how-do-you-load-data-from-a-remote-server-into-a-fragment-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

becuase currenlty you are trying to accessing UI elements from doInBackground method of AsyncTask. you will need to move all UI update related code  from doInBackground in onPostExecute as :

```
class GetCategories extends AsyncTask<String, String, 
                     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {
 String ipaddress="";
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
          //your code here...
           Bundle b = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
           ipaddress = b.getString("IPAddress");
        }

        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> 
                           doInBackground(String... param) {


           // Your code here...

            return categoryList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

              // update ListView here 

             ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> arrayAdapter = 
                  new ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>
                                (getActivity().
                    getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_menu_category);
            arrayAdapter.add(result);
            Your_ListActivity.this.setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }
```